# To Setup a Kong Gateway

Tags: docker, dns, kong

We have completed the basic setup for the kong(API creation and subscription), Next proceeded with kong gateway setup by following steps:

1. Kong Gateway Configuration:
   Created declarative configuration YAML file i.e kong.yaml

   _format_version: "2.1"

```
    services:
    - name: my-service
      url: https://<Hostname>/httpbin
      plugins:
      - name: oneapi
        config:
          api_version_shortname: kongdocumentation-v0
          authentication:
            authentication_type: apikey
      routes:
      - name: my-route
        paths:
        - /
```

2. Started to run kong gateway using 'docker run' command by adjusting the placeholders.

```
    docker run --name kong -d \
      --env KONG_ONEAPI_ENVIRONMENT=<your_environment> \
      --env KONG_ONEAPI_GATEWAY_KEY=<your_gateway_key> \
      --env KONG_ONEAPI_GATEWAY_SECRET=<your_gateway_secret> \
      --env KONG_DATABASE=off \
      --env KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=/kong_dbless/kong.yaml \
      --env KONG_LOG_LEVEL=info \
      -v $PWD/kong.yaml:/kong_dbless/kong.yaml \
      -p 8000:8000 -p 8100:8100 kong:latest
```

3. While I check if the gateway has been authorized succesfully to the API management backend by using the curl request to the exposed status endpoint, not getting the expected output.

From checking the logs of the created container, we are getting an error response.

Error:

```
2022/03/04 12:30:43 [error] 1098#0: *4 [kong] cache_manager.lua:156 [cache] failed to connect to Redis: [cosocket] DNS resolution failed: dns client error: 101 empty record received. Tried: ["(short):(na) - cache-miss",".apac.bg.corpintra.net:33 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/try 1 error: bad name/scheduled/querying/try 2 error: bad name/dns lookup pool exceeded retries (1): bad name",":33 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/dns client error: 101 empty record received",".apac.bg.corpintra.net:1 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/try 1 error: bad name/scheduled/querying/try 2 error: bad name/dns lookup pool exceeded retries (1): bad name",":1 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/dns client error: 101 empty record received",".apac.bg.corpintra.net:5 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/try 1 error: bad name/scheduled/querying/try 2 error: bad name/dns lookup pool exceeded retries (1): bad name",":5 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/dns client error: 101 empty record received"], context: ngx.timer

2022/03/04 12:30:43 [error] 1098#0: *4 [kong] cache_manager.lua:90 redis sanity check failed: failed to check gateway redis prefix: [cosocket] DNS resolution failed: dns client error: 101 empty record received. Tried: ["(short):(na) - cache-miss",".apac.bg.corpintra.net:33 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/try 1 error: bad name/scheduled/querying/try 2 error: bad name/dns lookup pool exceeded retries (1): bad name",":33 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/dns client error: 101 empty record received",".apac.bg.corpintra.net:1 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/try 1 error: bad name/scheduled/querying/try 2 error: bad name/dns lookup pool exceeded retries (1): bad name",":1 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/dns client error: 101 empty record received",".apac.bg.corpintra.net:5 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/try 1 error: bad name/scheduled/querying/try 2 error: bad name/dns lookup pool exceeded retries (1): bad name",":5 - cache-miss/scheduled/querying/dns client error: 101 empty record received"], context: ngx.timer
```

Can anyone let me know what is missing,

Comment: Error is quite clear, the host configuration is triggering the issue `bad name",":33`

Answer (score 0):

If your service is running on the host machine and not inside the docker network (where kong is) then you need to refer to it correctly with:

```
host.docker.internal
```

There is a video here with an example of what you are trying to do:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZZEKyH0MHQ